# I cant use multiple credentials on JMeter Authorization Manager on the same Test Case

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, http-authentication

I am trying to simulate a scenario where two different users(with different credentials) log in simultaneously. This simulation will continue in a controlled number of iterations loop.

I am using the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to generate the Transaction controllers when I record my user interactions.
I made two different Thread Groups to resemble each user with their separate Recording Controllers.

I first target one of the Recording Controller in my Test Script Recorder and then record myself logging in as `user1`. This autogenerates an HTTP Authorization Manager with the credentials.
When I now log in as a different user and record myself this time targeting another thread it does not generate an HTTP Authorization Manager. I then created my own manually and saved it as a txt file. When i try and play the recordings only the auto-generated one works.

What can I do to have two concurrent threads log in as different users or use the same thread group and have it switch between the two login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your credentials in the [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

```
username,password
user1,secret
user2,anothersecret
```

and add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to read the credentials from the CSV file into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

Then in the HTTP Authorization Manager just use the JMeter Variables from the CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

This way each thread (virtual user) will the next line from the CSV file on each iteration and you will be authenticated as a new user.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! you are a legend :).
It worked very well.

Comment: Is there a file that I can see all the recorded http requests in a continuous text format